# ABAdressbook get FullName from Telephonenumber

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

Hi 
I want to search the ABAdressbook and get the name from a given telephone number? 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
There are just a few ways of interacting with `ABAdressBook`.

The most impartant ones are saving or deleting `ABPerson` entrys by giving IDs and the [ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). It seems, this is for reasons of privacy, so that the only way to get info out of th AB is over the user.

**EDIT:**

Maybe i was wrong... check out if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781211/abaddressbook-store-values-in-nsdictionary) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

look at https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper
there is a method called contactsMatchingPhone which is what you want to use.

```
NSArray *match = [ABContactsHelper contactsMatchingPhone:@"your number"];
```

You can then use the ABContact helper to iterate through the results.